# Convexity of KL-Divergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, information-theory

If $0\leq \lambda \leq 1$, and we have probability mass functions $p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2$, then using the log sum inequality we can show that

${\displaystyle D_{\mathrm {KL} }(\lambda p_{1}+(1-\lambda )p_{2}\|\lambda q_{1}+(1-\lambda )q_{2})\leq \lambda D_{\mathrm {KL} }(p_{1}\|q_{1})+(1-\lambda )D_{\mathrm {KL} }(p_{2}\|q_{2})}$

How about the case where $p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2$ are pdfs (continuous random variables)?

Do we have a similar thing for continuous random variables?

Comment: Check your proof for the discrete case, you'll note that it uses the fact that the log-sum inequality holds pointwise for every $x$ in the sample space. That is, if you fix $x$, and let $a_1 = \lambda p_1(x), a_2 = (1-\lambda)p_2(x), b_1 = \lambda q_1(x), b_2 = (1-\lambda)q_2(x),$ then the inequality stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_sum_inequality) holds. Since integration is monotone, just as summation is, this suffices to prove the required inequality for continuous random variables.

Comment: I'm having trouble showing even the first statement i.e. that D_KL is convex w.r.t. its first argument. Can you please post an answer on my question here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3963943/proving-convexity-of-kl-divergence-w-r-t-first-argument