# Proving Convexity of KL Divergence w.r.t. first argument?

Tags: convex-optimization, information-theory

I'd like to show that the KL divergence is convex w.r.t. its first argument, where the KL divergence is defined as

$KL(q|p) = \sum_x q(x) \log \frac{q(x)}{p(x)}$

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452068/convexity-of-kl-divergence) suggests that I can show convexity using the log sum inequality, but thus far, I've only been able to show that $KL(\lambda q + (1-\lambda) r | p) \geq 0$. Can someone help me?

Comment: Isn't $u\mapsto\log(1/u)$ convex?

Comment: The simplest (and only) proof I've seen showing convexity of the KL divergence uses an argument based on perspective functions. There are a handful of papers on this, e.g. [here](http://pcombet.math.ncsu.edu/svva4.pdf). It may be much simpler if you only focus on a single argument though.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first rewrite $\mathrm{KL}$ slightly more conveniently: $$ \mathrm{KL}(q\|p) = \sum q(x) \log q(x) - \sum q(x) \log p(x).$$ The second of these terms is linear in $q$, so you only need to argue that $\varphi(q) := \sum q(x) \log q(x)$ is convex. This follows because the function $u \mapsto u \log u$ with $0 \log 0 := 0$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$. One way to show this is the log-sum inequality: for any $u_1, u_2$ and $\lambda \in (0,1),$ take $a_1 = \lambda u_1, a_2 = (1-\lambda) u_2, b_1 = \lambda, b_2 = (1-\lambda)$, in which case the log-sum inequality tells us that $$ \lambda u_1\log u_1 + (1-\lambda) u_2 \log u_2 \ge (\lambda u_1 + (1-\lambda) u_2) \log \frac{(\lambda u_1 + (1-\lambda) u_2)}{(\lambda + 1 - \lambda)}. $$

Now we can use this inequality term by term in the sum in $\varphi$. Let $\lambda \in (0,1)$. Then $$ \varphi(\lambda q_1 + (1-\lambda)q_2) =  \sum (\lambda q_1(x) + (1-\lambda)q_2(x)) \log (\lambda q_1(x) + (1-\lambda)q_2(x)) \\ \le \sum \lambda q_1(x) \log q_1(x) +  (1-\lambda) q_2(x) \log q_2(x) \\ = \lambda \sum q_1(x) \log q_1(x) +  (1-\lambda) \sum q_2(x) \log q_2(x) \\ = \lambda \varphi(q_1) + (1-\lambda) \varphi(q_2). $$

(Formally, for each $x$, we're using the inequality above with $u_1 = q_1(x)$ and $u_2 = q_2(x)$.)

In fact pretty much the same argument applies to directly arguing the joint convexity of $\mathrm{KL}$ in $(p,q)$ - set $b_1 = \lambda v_1$ and $b_2 = (1-\lambda) v_2$ to show the joint convexity of $(u,v) \mapsto u \log \frac{u}{v},$ and then use the same term-by-term approach.